# Is there a good way python to compare complex dictionaries with unkonwn depth & level

Tags: python

I have two dictionary objects which are very complex and created by converting large xml files into python dictionaries.

I don't know the depth of the dictionaries and just want to compare and want the following output...

e.g. My dictionaries are like this

```
d1 = {"great grand father":
         {"name":"John",
          "grand father":
             {"name":"Tom",
              "father":
                 {"name":"Andy",
                  "Me":
                     {"name":"Mike",
                      "son": 
                         {"name":"Tom"}
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
     }
```

d2 is also a similar but could be possible any one of the field is missing or changed as below

```
d2 = {"great grand father":
         {"name":"John",
          "grand father":
             {"name":"Tom",
              "father":
                 {"name":"Andy",
                  "Me":
                     {"name":"Tonny",
                      "son": 
                         {"name":"Tom"}
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
     }
```

The dictionary comparison should give me results like this -

```
Expected Key/Val : Me->name/"Mike" 
Actual Key/Val : Me->name/"Tonny"
```

If the key "name" does not exists in "Me" in d2, it should give me following output

```
Expected Key/Val : Me->name/"Mike" 
Actual Key/Val : Me->name/NOT_FOUND
```

I repeat the dictionary depth could be variable or dynamically generated. The two dictionaries here are given as examples...

All the dictionary comparison questions and their answers which I have seen in SO are related fixed depth Dictionaries.....

Comment: There are plenty of syntax errors in your dictionaries.

Comment: The comparison that you want to make is still not clear to me.

Comment: @interjay OK... I did the changes and now the syntax errors are removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I found a way to compare any two dictionaries -

I have tried with various dictionaries of any depths and worked for me. The code is not so modular but just for the reference -

```
import pprint

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)

dict1 = { 'Person' : { 'Male' : {'Boys' : {'Roger' : {'age' : 20},
                                           'Rafa' : {'age' : 25}
                                          }
                                },
                       'Female' : { 'Girls' : {'Serena' : {'age' : 23},
                                               'Maria' : {'age' : 15}
                                              }
                                  }

                     },
          'Animal' : { 'Huge' : {'Elephant' : {'color' : 'black' }
                                }
                     }
        }
'''
dict2 = { 'Person' : { 'Male' : {'Boys' : {'Roger' : {'age' : 20}
                                          }
                                },
                       'Female' : { 'Girls' : {'Serena' : {'age' : 23},
                                               'Maria' : {'age' : 1}
                                              }
                                  }
                     }
        }

dict2 = { 'Person' : { 'Male' : {'Boys' : {'Roger' : {'age' : 20},
                                           'Rafa' : {'age' : 2}
                                          }
                                }
                     }
        }
'''

dict2 = { 'Person' : { 'Male' : {'Boys' : {'Roger' : {'age' : 2}}},
                       'Female' : 'Serena'}
        }


key_list = []
err_list = {}
def comp(exp,act):
    for key in exp:
        key_list.append(key)
        exp_val = exp[key]
        try:
            act_val = act[key]
            is_dict_exp = isinstance(exp_val,__builtins__.dict)
            is_dict_act = isinstance(act_val,__builtins__.dict)

            if is_dict_exp == is_dict_act == True:
                comp(exp_val,act_val)
            elif is_dict_exp == is_dict_act == False:
                if not exp_val == act_val:
                    temp = {"Exp" : exp_val,"Act" : act_val}
                    err_key = "-->".join(key_list)
                    if err_list.has_key(key):
                        err_list[err_key].update(temp)
                    else:
                        err_list.update({err_key : temp})
            else:
                temp = {"Exp" : exp_val, "Act" : act_val}
                err_key = "-->".join(key_list)
                if err_list.has_key(key):
                    err_list[err_key].update(temp)
                else:
                    err_list.update({err_key : temp})

        except KeyError:
            temp = {"Exp" : exp_val,"Act" : "NOT_FOUND"}
            err_key = "-->".join(key_list)
            if err_list.has_key(key):
                err_list[err_key].update(temp)
            else:
                err_list.update({err_key : temp})
        key_list.pop()

comp(dict1,dict2)

pp.pprint(err_list)
```

Here is the output of my code -

```
{   'Animal': {   'Act': 'NOT_FOUND',
                  'Exp': {   'Huge': {   'Elephant': {   'color': 'black'}}}},
    'Person-->Female': {   'Act': 'Serena',
                           'Exp': {   'Girls': {   'Maria': {   'age': 15},
                                                   'Serena': {   'age': 23}}}},
    'Person-->Male-->Boys-->Rafa': {   'Act': 'NOT_FOUND', 'Exp': {   'age': 25}},
    'Person-->Male-->Boys-->Roger-->age': {   'Act': 2, 'Exp': 20}
}
```

One can also try with other dictionaries given in commented code..

One more thing - The keys are checked in expected dictionary and the matched with an actual. If we pass dictionaries in alternate order the other way matching is also possible...

```
comp(dict2,dict1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're in luck, I did this as part of a project where I worked.

You need a recursive function something like:

```
def checkDifferences(dict_a,dict_b,differences=[])
```

You can first check for keys that don't exist in one or the other.
e.g

```
Expected Name/Tom Actual None
```

Then you compare the types of the values i.e check if the value is a dict or a list etc.

If it is then you can recursively call the function using the value as dict_a/b. When calling recursively pass the differences array.

If the type of the value is a list and the list may have dictionaries within it then you need to covert the list to a dict and call the function on the converted dictionary.

I'm sorry I can't help more but I no longer have access to the source code. Hopefully this is enough to get you started.

Comment: instead of passing the array you can yield results.  in python 3.2 you can use `yield from` for the recursive call, otherwise you need to iterate over it and yield explicitly.

Comment: The function I wrote used Python 2.7 but yes yield is a good idea.

Comment: As I mentioned at the bottom of my answer, unfortunately I no longer have access to the source code. I just remember the basis of how it worked.